# Merge Joint accounts into single row SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I know there are a lot of articles out there that show you how to PIVOT data and return different outputs but i am really struggling with this. I need to transform data which presents as multiple rows into a single row.

THe table I have contains the following

```
RefNo   | Title | FirstName | LastName  | DOB        | TelNumber | MultipleAcounts
2211700 | Mr    | Marshal   | Seaton    |03/12/1980  | 012365487 | J
2211700 | Mrs   | Dallas    | Seaton    |01/01/1978  | 012345697 | J
```

And transform it to

```
RefNo   | Title | FirstName | LastName  | DOB        | TelNumber | MultipleAcounts | J Title    | J FirstName | J Surname | J DOB      | J TEl     | J 
2211700 | Mr    | Marshal   | Seaton    |03/12/1980  | 012365487 | J               | Mrs    | Dallas      | Seaton    |01/01/1978  | 012345697 | J
```

I've dane a couple of different joins but always end up back with duplicate data.

Comment: What do you want as result 1.If there's no duplicate on RefNo ? 2.If they are 3 (or more) similiar RefNo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. This only works when you know there will only be a maximum of 2 rows per RefNo.

```
declare @Something table
(
    RefNo int
    , Title varchar(5)
    , FirstName varchar(25)
    , LastName varchar(25)
    , DOB date
    , TelNumber varchar(10)
    , MultipleAcounts char(1)
)
insert @Something
select 2211700, 'Mr', 'Marshal', 'Seaton', '03/12/1980', '012365487', 'J' union all
select 2211700, 'Mrs', 'Dallas', 'Seaton', '01/01/1978', '012345697', 'J';

with SortedVals as
(
    select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by RefNo order by Title) as RowNum
    from @Something
)

select RefNo
    , MAX(case RowNum when 1 then Title end) as Title
    , MAX(case RowNum when 1 then FirstName end) as FirstName
    , MAX(case RowNum when 1 then DOB end) as DOB
    , MAX(case RowNum when 1 then TelNumber end) as TelNumber
    , MAX(case RowNum when 1 then MultipleAcounts end) as MultipleAcounts
    , MAX(case RowNum when 2 then Title end) as Title2
    , MAX(case RowNum when 2 then FirstName end) as FirstName2
    , MAX(case RowNum when 2 then DOB end) as DOB2
    , MAX(case RowNum when 2 then TelNumber end) as TelNumber2
    , MAX(case RowNum when 2 then MultipleAcounts end) as MultipleAcounts2
from SortedVals
group by RefNo
```

If you want to read more about this approach OR if you need a dynamic version here is a great set of two articles about this technique.

[Cross Tabs and Pivots, Part 1 – Converting Rows to Columns](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/)

[Cross Tabs and Pivots, Part 2 - Dynamic Cross Tabs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/)